# Use oracle to count json in clob column

Tags: sql, arrays, json, oracle, count

Given:

```
 t_user
   ID (NUMBER)
   USERNAME (VARCHAR2)
   JSON_DATA (CLOB)
```

JSON_DATA contains JSON structure:

```
ID | username | JSON_DATA
1  | example  | {"hobbies": ["football", "climbing"]}
1  | example  | {"hobbies": ["football", "tennis"]}
```

How can i make a oracle select, which counts the grouped hobbies:

```
football: 2
climbing: 1
tennis: 1
```

I know there is something like json_table, json_value and json_array.
Perhaps someone can tell me how to write this in this new oracle syntax.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use `json_table()`:

```
select j.hobby, count(*) cnt
from t_user u
cross apply json_table(
    u.json_data, 
    '$.hobbies[*]' columns (hobby varchar2(50) path '$')
) j
group by j.hobby
```

**[Demo on DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=73df73998377914e4c9e991fc1dbea7f)**:

```
HOBBY    | CNT
:------- | --:
climbing |   1
football |   2
tennis   |   1
```